# Include a checkbox in Twitter Bootstrap drop-down menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to include checkbox in Twitter Bootstrap drop-down menu's but I'm unable to get the menu text (in <a>..</a>) to sit beside the checkbox. I have read up on the CSS used for Forms and have tried a variety of things to no avail.

This is what I think should work, but doesn't.

```
<li><label class="checkbox" ><input type="checkbox">aaa</label><a href="#" style="float:left"></a></li>
```

Neville

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7c4/)
But there is some [problem](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2097)

Comment: Thanks Oleg, looks good. I am aware of the problem re. Issue 2097 and I don't think that will be difficult to resolve.

I actually want to use <a>menu text</a> and by adding a new css rule that works fine.

Thanks again for your help, Neville

Comment: Looks like the issue's been updated. Now you just need to add the `dropdown-menu-form` class to the parent `<ul>` and it works great.

Answer (score 12):

A line of javascript to resolve the problem in Oleg answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Wsc9r/

Comment: This is the ideal way to approach this. This way there is no need to modify bootstrap.js

Answer (score 10):

Wrap your checkbox into A-tag like this:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            Some text
        </label>
    </a>
</li>
```

Also you may add this CSS rules

```
.dropdown-menu input {margin-top: -4px;}
.dropdown-menu label {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The accepted answer is full of &nbsp;. It's too hackish.

Comment: Yeah, this works best. By the way, bootstrap has a checkbox class to line up items, so you might not need to define your own CSS.

Comment: in addition to using `<a>` tags I added `.checkbox` but overrided `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to make the spacing more natural. EG: `<a class="checkbox" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px>checkbox labels and inputs</a>`. Maybe similar to CSS rules posted in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this jquery plugin for bootstrap : https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: This answer may be discouraged, but the Bootstrap Multiselect plugin is awesome!

Comment: @kleopatra the accepted answer to this question is link-only. Complain there.

Comment: @Bardware it's just a gentle reminder of the site rules - so why do you feel the need to be rude ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Heare is a good example of that:
https://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/fboKH

And heare is the code:

```js
var options = [];



$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {

  var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;

  if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
    options.splice(idx, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', false)
    }, 0);
  } else {
    options.push(val);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $inp.prop('checked', true)
    }, 0);
  }

  $(event.target).blur();


  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 6</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running Chrome on Windows 10, each item's checkbox is not vertically aligned with the corresponding text. People looking for something that is in line with user expectations will need to modify this example a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()   {
                $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
        </script>

</head>
<body>

    <select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Choice01</option>
        <option value="2">Choice02</option>
        <option value="3">Choice03</option>
        <option value="4">Choice04</option>
        <option value="5">Choice05</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```